# How to pass props from an extended class in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Recently I've been working in a project where I need to keep the code as cleanest as possible. That's why I'm working in a component which needs to extends some characteristics from another one, but I also need to pass some props to obtain some behavior in return. But there is a problem: I'm adding a prop in the constructor, but there is a function that doesn't receive/seem have that prop:

```
class SampleClassOne extends PureComponent<Props>{
   Constructor(Props){
     console.log(props)    // In this console.log, the variable aditionalVar appears 
     super(props){
     {
   }
   functionOne(){
     const {
       varOne,
       varTwo,
       varThree,
       aditionalVar
     } = this.props
     console.log(this.props)  // In this console.log, the variable aditionalVar does not appear
     render(){
     ...
     }
   } 
}
class SampleClassTwo extends SampleClassOne {
   Constructor(Props){
     super({...props, aditionalVar: true})  // This is where I'm adding the new variable
     }
   }
}
```

I don't know if I'm clear with the question I'm asking... how can I make sure that new variables I'm adding from components that extends from others can be received by all the component that extends its class.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It's actually anti-pattern in React to extend other components. React favors composition over inheritance, see https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html Also, is this a typo `Constructor(Props)`? It should be `constructor(props)`.

Comment: Sure... I'll check that link, thanks. And you're right, I wrote it uppercase, but it is constructor(props)

Comment: check out function components (react hooks). the code becomes much simpler than it's with class components and it will make your life easier..